# Threepenny-GUI: Get Attribute Value as String

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

is there a way to get the attribute value (especially the id) of an element as a string?
For instance the following lines result in "()":

```
field <- UI.new
    # set (attr "id") "some text"


on UI.drop field $ \_ -> do

    -- Some label to print the attribute value to   
    label <- getElementById window "labelID"

    id <- get (attr "id") field
    (element (fromJust label)) # set text (show id)
```

Since `attr` returns a `WriteAttr`, `get` might not be working. Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of threepenny-gui v0.8.1.0, this is currently not implemented. It's certainly possible, I just haven't gotten around to do that yet. Feel free to open an issue on Github!

(Note that you can always call JavaScript directly with the `runFunction` and `ffi` functions if you are missing functionality.)